# Handle @NotBlank errors - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm trying to handle exceptions thrown through the by the `@NotBlank` annotation in a Spring Boot application. The code I have so far handles the `MethodArgumentNotValidException` thrown by `@Size` and `@Email` annotations. However when I expect a `@NotBlank` message to be returned, I instead get an empty response body, indicating to me that a different type of exception is being thrown, but it's not clear to me which one:

See the model being validated:

```kotlin
import javax.validation.constraints.Email
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import javax.validation.constraints.Size

data class SignupDto(
    @field:NotBlank(message = "Email Address is mandatory.")
    @field:Email(message = "Email Address is invalid.")
    val emailAddress: String,

    @field:NotBlank(message = "First Name is mandatory.")
    @field:Size(min = 2, max = 255, message = "First Name must be between 2 and 255 characters.")
    val firstName: String,

    @field:Size(min = 2, max = 255, message = "Last Name must be between 2 and 255 characters.")
    val lastName: String? = null,

    @field:NotBlank(message = "Password is mandatory")
    val password: String
)
```

And the handler

```kotlin
package com.travisalexandersmith.runjamaicaapi.auth

import com.travisalexandersmith.runjamaicaapi.auth.exceptions.EmailAddressTakenException
import com.travisalexandersmith.runjamaicaapi.global.responses.ErrorMessage
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler

@ControllerAdvice
class AuthControllerAdvisor : ResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("AuthControllerAdvisor")

    @ExceptionHandler(EmailAddressTakenException::class)
    fun handleEmailAddressTakenExceptions(
        exception: EmailAddressTakenException,
        request: WebRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage> {
        logger.info(exception.message)
        val errorMessage = ErrorMessage(exception.message)
        return ResponseEntity<ErrorMessage>(errorMessage, HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
    }

    override fun handleMethodArgumentNotValid(
        ex: MethodArgumentNotValidException,
        headers: HttpHeaders,
        status: HttpStatus,
        request: WebRequest
    ): ResponseEntity<Any> {
        val fieldErrors = ex.bindingResult.fieldErrors.map { it.defaultMessage }
        return ResponseEntity<Any>(ErrorMessage(error = "Invalid request body.", details = fieldErrors), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    }
}
```

Here is the associated controller:

```kotlin
package com.travisalexandersmith.runjamaicaapi.auth

import com.travisalexandersmith.runjamaicaapi.auth.dto.SignupDto
import com.travisalexandersmith.runjamaicaapi.auth.responses.AuthResponse
import com.travisalexandersmith.runjamaicaapi.auth.services.AuthService
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import javax.validation.Valid


@RestController
@RequestMapping("auth")
@Validated
class AuthController @Autowired constructor(val authService: AuthService) {
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("AuthController")

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    fun signup(@Valid @RequestBody signupDto: SignupDto): AuthResponse {
        logger.info("Request to signup for user with email address ${signupDto.emailAddress}")
        return authService.signup(signupDto)
    }
}
```

What should I add here to manage the exceptions for `@NotBlank`?

Comment: How are you testing/using the validation? In controller methods, or in service methods?

Comment: The validation is on the controller method, I added it to the question

Comment: That is weird, `MethodArgumentNotValidException` should be the correct one. Maybe you can add another method with a catch-all `Exception` and debug what exception you get exactly? You can also take some inspiration from my open-source library [Error Handling Spring Boot Starter](https://github.com/wimdeblauwe/error-handling-spring-boot-starter) (or just use it instead of your own handler if it fits your requirements).

Comment: Oddly I'm only able to see the error that's being thrown if I don't extend `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` it's throwing a `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException` I'll update the question with more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to see the error until I stopped extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` in the controller once I did I saw this error coming from the `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.MissingKotlinParameterException: Instantiation of [simple type, class com.travisalexandersmith.runjamaicaapi.auth.dto.SignupDto] value failed for JSON property emailAddress due to missing (therefore NULL) value for creator parameter emailAddress which is a non-nullable type
```

The issue is the fields in the `SignupDto` had to be marked as nullable otherwise this exception will be thrown when they are missing:

```kotlin
data class SignupDto(
    @field:NotBlank(message = "Email Address is mandatory.")
    @field:Email(message = "Email Address is invalid.")
    val emailAddress: String?,

    @field:NotBlank(message = "First Name is mandatory.")
    @field:Size(min = 2, max = 255, message = "First Name must be between 2 and 255 characters.")
    val firstName: String?,

    @field:Size(min = 2, max = 255, message = "Last Name must be between 2 and 255 characters.")
    val lastName: String? = null,

    @field:NotBlank(message = "Password is mandatory")
    val password: String?
)
```